# Qual a sintaxe correta para linear-gradiente (CSS) no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando manipular um *background* com `onmouseover`/`onmouseout` e me deparei com a seguinte questão:

Como a sintaxe CSS abaixo ficaria no JavaScript?

```
background-image: linear-gradient( to top, rgba(23,35,34,0.55), transparent);
```

Já tentei isto, entre outras variações mais não consegui fazer funcionar...

```
var barra_off = document.getElementById("idboxControl");

function func_barra_off(){

barra_off.style.backgroundImage ="linearGradient( to top,rgba(23,35,34,0), transparent);"

barra_off.style.webkitTransition ="0.5s ease-out";

}
```

Alguém?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os erros são:

- Em vez de `linearGradient`, seria `linear-gradient`. O *camelCase* é apenas na propriedade do JavaScript, o valor tem a mesma sintaxe usada no CSS.
- Não pode conter o ponto e vírgula no final do valor, senão o valor se torna inválido.

Seria:

```
barra_off.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient( to top,rgba(23,35,34,0), transparent)";
```

Um exemplo alterando o canal alpha do rgba para 1 para poder visualizar o efeito:

```js
var barra_off = document.getElementById("idboxControl");

function func_barra_off(){
   barra_off.style.backgroundImage ="linear-gradient( to top,rgba(23,35,34,1), transparent)"
   barra_off.style.webkitTransition ="0.5s ease-out";
}
```

```css
#idboxControl{
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="idboxControl" onmouseover="func_barra_off()">
   passe o mouse
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado Sam! Super didática sua explicação. Resolvido :D

Answer (score 2):

A sintaxe é exatamente a mesma que você utilizou no CSS, pois os campos de `HTMLElement.style` trabalham com a mesma sintaxe utilizada pelos estilos *inline* do elemento. O detalhe é que você não deve passar o ponto-e-vírgula ao final:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');

div.style.height = '100px';
div.style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient( to top, rgba(23,35,34,0.55), transparent)';
```

```html
<div></div>
```